# Geodesic speed not working

Tags: math

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503580/geodesic-speed-not-working) has been on the site for a long time, so, mathematically speaking, every correction has been made. Now ... What is wrong with the code from a programmer's point of view?

Comment: If the code is `BASIC` why is this tagged `C`?

Comment: There's an answer on http://math.stackexchange.com saying the maths is wrong.  The coding is dubious too; it looks as though it is assuming that multiplication binds tighter than division (as in maths, and unlike in most computing languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 variables `vr, vphi, r, phi` are being updated sequentially, yet they are used in each other's equations.  Consider updating them into a temporary set of new values, so each equation uses the same old value.  After all done, perform the update.

```
vrNext = vr + (12/(r^7+4*r)*vr^2) *ds + (r^8/(4*r+r^7)*vphi^2) *ds
vphiNext = vphi + (-2/r*vr*vphi) *ds
rNext = r + vr*ds
phiNext = phi + vphi*ds

vr = vrNext
vphi = vphiNext
r = rNext
phi = phiNext
```

Comment: You're a genius! :D How could I forget that! Face palm! Thank you very much!!

Comment: But sadly this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please present more info about the problem's symptoms and also post your code.  Suggest a new question, but be certain to reference this one and show how you have a _subsequent_ issue.  Further, I've noticed somewhat hostile responses to posts the do not have a clear _specific_ question (with a question mark) like this one.